# Using Fn or super (windows) keys to define new shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

Is there any way to use <kbd>Fn</kbd> or <kbd>super</kbd> (windows) to define new keyboard shortcut in PhpStorm?
(Almost all key combinations are allocated right now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you can't do it directly since Java will not recognize such key codes, however there is a workaround using third-party tools like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

The idea is to map a keyboard shortcut that is not recognized by Java to the one that is recognized but is not already used because it's hard to type manually.

For example, to map <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> use the following script in AutoHotkey:

`#n::^!+z`

Now you can map any action to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in PhpStorm `Settings` | `Keymap`.

Abilty to use <kbd>Fn</kbd> key would depend on the particular keyboard. If this key sends separate key code that can be recognized by Autohotkey, then you can map it the way described above. My Logitech keyboard has <kbd>Fn</kbd> key that doesn't send a key code and therefore cannot be used. However, I was able to map <kbd>ALT GR</kbd> key (right alt) using <kbd>AppsKey</kbd> in AutoHotkey.